# Marshmallow Schema doesn't have data and error field on different computer. Code is the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

[Server version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkCdP.png)

[Local Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRR9Y.png)

Apparently I'm not allowed to embed images so here are some links.

When I run my code (Pyhon Flask Marshmallow SQLAlchemy) on my machine the "data" and "error" fields are outputted properly by jsonify.

When I run my code on a digital ocean droplet the fields don't get jsonified. I'm not sure why because their contents are still there.

This appears to be an issue with all my flask applications on the server. I have verified that the data and error fields exist by adapting the code to return .data and this returns fine.

Here is the code from this example of this happening:

```
    return jsonify(meme_schemas.dump(
    [
        Meme.query.filter_by(id=id1).first(),
        Meme.query.filter_by(id=id2).first()
    ]))
```

jsonify is a function from flask.
meme_schemas.dump converts the Meme SQLAlchemy model into a combination of JSON equivalent types in python. (Using Marshmallow I didn't write the conversion code)

The only differences other than hardware is the droplet runs python 3.5 and my laptop runs 3.6.5

I should probably have used a more serious example rather than one from this dumb practice project

Comment: I'm sorry if this is too vague I've been trying to work out what's going on for the last hour
I have the workaround of just sending "data" back instead but I'd rather do this properly.